# RAID 0 arrangement for max IOPS with mechanical drives

Tags: raid, hyper-v, virtual-machines

We need to run a high number of low-resource VMs concurrently in 2012 R2 Hyper-V.  We've experimented with various configurations and using Perfmon.exe for reporting, we've found we're bottlenecking hard on IO.

Storage and data retention are of no concern for these boxes, so given a maximum combination of 4 mechanical drives for each server (we're avoiding SSDs for other reasons), what would give us the best IOPS with a large number of VMs?

The main concern is IO contention, if we have 12 VMs running on a four disk array, then wouldn't, say, 5 VMs doing IO operations cause contention for the remaining?  If we split it into two arrays of two, would that resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk I/O is subject to the [tragedy of the commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons). With <strike>sheep</strike> mechanical disks, you have a hard ceiling for your <strike>grass</strike> random I/O. The only way to keep one bad actor from starving out the rest of the <strike>sheep</strike> VMs is to keep it on it's own <strike>patch of grass</strike> set of disks. Confining the greedy <strike>sheep</strike> VMs to their own pen will allow the rest to get resources more often than they would in a communal setting.

So yes, splitting your array will help reduce contention for the non-greedy VMs. It will greatly enhance it for the greedy ones, though.

Comment: This is my favorite response I've read on any stackexchange community.  Also that clears that up, thank you.